# extbase not found exception redirect to 404 default page

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I have a extension and when I call this extension with an ID of a record that not or no longer exists I get an Exception `Object of type My\Model\... with identity "1035" not found.`

The page itself got the header status 500.

What I would like to do in this case is to show my default 404 page. Is this possible? And how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using a method like

```
public function detailAction(\YourVendor\Ext\Domain\Model\MyModel $model)
```

In that case, it is not that easy because the exception is already thrown in extbase's core. You can take a look how I solve it for my [news extension](https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Classes/Controller/NewsBaseController.php#L43-L83):

```
   /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param ResponseInterface $response
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function processRequest(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        try {
            parent::processRequest($request, $response);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->handleKnownExceptionsElseThrowAgain($exception);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param \Exception $exception
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function handleKnownExceptionsElseThrowAgain(\Exception $exception)
    {
        $previousException = $exception->getPrevious();
        if (
            $this->actionMethodName === 'detailAction'
            && $previousException instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception
            && isset($this->settings['detail']['errorHandling'])
        ) {
            $this->handleNoNewsFoundError($this->settings['detail']['errorHandling']);
        } else {
            throw $exception;
        }
    }
```

In the method `handleNoNewsFoundError` you can do then anything you want to, e.g. calling `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->pageNotFoundAndExit('No news entry found.');`.

Comment: exactly I use the default `showAction` created with the extension-builder. You solutions works perfectly. For others: You have to declare the namespace or use the full path in the processRequest functionvariables.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but from a logical POV you should just catch the exception and then let your controller decide what to do (in your case: show a 404 page).